# Ellipsometry measurments

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, laser, lenses

Why it is good to measure on a wavelength range in ellipsometry instead of using a single wavelength. I understand this that the measured data (ψ and ∆ ) plotted against wavelength and if we have single wavelength we will get ψ against only a single wavelength. hence reduced information . Is it correct ?